# Why does the first block compile correctly?

Tags: java, arrays, list, types, variable-assignment

```
Object[] o = new Object[3];  
String[] s = new String[3];

o = s; //compiles
o[0] = new Date();

List<Object> o2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> s2 = new ArrayList<>();

o2 = s2; //does not compile
```

I dont understand why the first block of code `o=s;` compiles correctly and the assignment of `o2=s2;` therefor is wrong.

Comment: because an array of `String`s is an array of `Object`s, whereas an List of `String`s is not a list of `Object`s.

Comment: Or, more precisely, a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`.

Comment: But note that a `List<String>` is a `List<? extends Object>`.